# What is the best way to make sure a thread is ticking with exactly one second?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Considering this is my code:

```
    public void alarmClockTick()
    {
        while(true){

            foreach(Alarm alarm in objectCollection){

                //Do some actions

            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

If we suppose the for-loop does some action which might take a few ms, how can I make sure the thread loop cycles after exactly 1 second? I am currently working on an alarm clock, and I would like to have precision in this part of my code.

I thought about measuring the time needed for the loop and then calculate the time we need to wait, but however, the time measure would take some time as well?

How would I approach this problem?

Comment: Use a Timer which does the ticking for you

Comment: @helb a timer isn't precise to be exactly 1 second and it has the exact same problem he mentions. You could do something like start a stopwatch at the beginning, stop it at the end, calculate how much time it took then do 1000 - thatTime. However, there are definitely things that could always cause inaccuracies. Threads don't just "run always" they swap in/out as other threads need the CPU.

Comment: @dman2306 Well, you only have reasonable and guaranteed precision in a real-time OS anyway...

Comment: First you have to tell us why it has to be exactly or what exactly is in your understanding. If you want to base some animations on this e.g. drawing the second indicator of a clock, your approach is wrong anyway.

Comment: @helb but my point is your solution provides no greater precision over what he already has so why change the code?

Comment: Don't use timers for thread synchronization - if you need to wait for a thread that does work, use synchronization primitives to signal from the thread that work is complete.

Comment: @dman2306 With a timer, you don't need to measure the time you spent with own code. It also is a standard mechanism that is well understood, documented and decouples the timing from the code to be executed.

Comment: You should update your question with details about what you're _actually_ trying to do. Using `Thread.Sleep()` is very rarely correct and, based on what's in your question, your problem is not one of those cases.

Comment: Look into using waithandles instead of Thread.Sleep() see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989435/conditional-periodic-timer-using-wait-handles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that Windows is not real time. If you use a timer, you will get a signal after a second, but there might be some delay.

The best way to handle that is to accept it and compensate for it. That is: 
Store the start time of your clock. Set a timer for a second. After each second set a new timer, but instead of setting it for a second again, calculate the number of milliseconds you lost in the previous second and set the timer for a corrected value. Keep using the original start time for this calculation and don't update that, because doing so may introduce another deviation. Just calculate the correction based on the original start time.

You may even need to drop a second now and then if there was a really heavy process running.

Answer (score 0):

Im taking a wild guess and assume all you want to do is more something like this. The code can be easily adopted for "alarmclock functionality"

Create a windows Form and add a Button called button1 and a label called label1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer _timer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 10;
        _timer.Tick += _updateLabel();

    }

    private void _updateLabel()
    {
        label1.Text = (DateTime.Now - _start).ToString();
    }

    DateTime _start;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_timer.Enabled)
        {
            _start = DateTime.Now;
            _timer.Start();
        }
        else _timer.Stop();
        _updateLabel();
    }
}
```